# Large scale pyramid application with multiple databases

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

This is less of a question, and more of a "am I on the right track with my train of thought?" topic.

I have an idea for a fairly large scale application written using Pyramid, using multiple databases, and wanted to post some of my musings to see if what I have in mind would work. I'm in the process of designing the application, but haven't started writing any code yet, to test out if it would work or not.

I'm considering it large scale because I anticipate the database growing significantly.

Main points:

- The main route would be in the form of [www.domain.com/[name]/whatever](http://www.domain.com/%5Bname%5D/whatever), where [name] is the key parameter that will decide what data to present to the client.
- There will be multiple databases: 1 database, let's say site.db that contains site-wide information and configs, and the rest of the databases will be [name].db, containing each individuals user-specific data. This is where I expect the bulk of the scaling to happen, as I want to design the application to accept 100s of databases, one per user, to compartmentalize the data and prevent data cross-contamination.

Options:

1. 2 databases. site.db and userdata.db. I would use the same database models, but the table names would be determined dynamically using the [name] parameter as such: [name]_table1, [name]_table2, etc, where table1/2/n would be a lot more descriptive than that. This may be simpler in the sense that I'd only ever have 2 database sessions to work with, and as long as I keep the sessions separate, I should be able to query each one individually. The downside is that the userdata.db can grow large with 100s of users. In theory, shouldn't be a problem if I can query the right tables using the [name] parameter.
2. 1 + n databases. Managing database sessions could be a pain here, but one possible solution might be to scan a folder for all .db files, and create a session for each database, and build out a dictionary of sessions, where the dictionary key would be the file name. Something like sessions['site'] points to the DB session that handles site-wide data, while session['name'] points to a session that manipulates name.db - if that makes sense. This way, I can use the [name] parameter in the route to use the appropriate database session.

---

Aside from the above, there will be a sub-application as well, in the form of an IRC bot, that will monitor for chat events and commands to manipulate the same databases. I'm thinking one way to do this would be to run instances of the IRC bot, passing in [name] as a parameter, so that each instance of the IRC bot is only accessing one database. There's still the possibility that the IRC bot and Pyramid application  may be trying to manipulate the same database, which could be problematic. Maybe one way around this would be for the IRC bot to import the database sessions (as mentioned above in point #2), and use the same sessions within the IRC bot application (would that take advantage of Pyramid's transaction manager? Presumably yes).

---

That's all I have right now. I hope I'm thinking about this correctly. Is there anything that I'm grossly mistaken on?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to unpack in your question and it's probably too much for SO but I have a few comments.

- I would strongly urge avoiding a per-tenant schema where you're doing dynamic naming of tables. So I'd avoid option 1. Session management is always difficult, and sort of depends on your choice of database (for example, pgbouncer can greatly help by keeping persistent connections open to a lot of databases without complicating your code as much).
- Manipulating the same database isn't the end of the world - any decent database has concurrency support and can handle multiple connections so long as you handle your locking correctly.
- Consider whether it's really worth separating the databases as it definitely adds a lot of complexity up front. It depends on the problem domain and use cases whether it's worth it.

Comment: The comments are appreciated. Thank you for the input. I definitely can design it in such a way to use only a single database. I suppose the tradeoff is between having a single database file (and one session) where the file can grow quite large, vs. having 100s of database sessions each with a smaller database file (each individual file won't grow that large because of the data is a smaller portion of the overall data).